# Elixir or Hex portable package format?

Tags: elixir

Is there any portable format for elixir code? Other than the obvious tar.

For example, if I wanted to provide one or more modules to a client or fellow developers on another team (without the use of github). How would I do that?

The answer in some other familiar languages are: Ruby - gem, Java - jar, Python - egg, ect.

Answer (score 24):

It depends on what you want to provide.

I will discuss three options below, all available through our build tool called Mix.

- [Hex](http://hex.pm) packages source files. If you want to provide code for other developers to use in their projects, Hex is the best option because it knows how to fetch and resolve dependencies too. Call `mix local.hex` to install it and then `mix local` to see all available Hex tasks;
- [Escript](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Escript.Build.html) allows you to bundle your whole project (including dependencies) into an executable that can be invoked from the command line. You need to have Erlang installed for escripts to work, you don't need to have Elixir installed though. Note an Escript **cannot** be used as a dependency by other projects.
- [Archives](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Archive.Build.html) are basically a tar of **compiled** artifacts that the Erlang runtime knows how to load. Archives do not include dependencies and, in Elixir, they are used only as plugins for the Mix build tool. For example, Hex above is installed as an archive inside Mix.

Comment: Doe Hex deploy whole applications? Or does it only work with libraries?

Comment: No, Hex is a package manager. It packages sources, not compiled code. It cannot be used for deployment. Links were updated.