# Can Elixir or Erlang programs be compiled to a standalone binary?

Tags: compilation, erlang, elixir

It says that Elixir has a tool called `elixirc` and Erlang has a tool called `erlc` to [compile modules](http://elixir-lang.org/crash-course.html#elixir) for use. It says immediately after this that you can then run code with the `elixir` command line tool.

Is there a way to compile a binary executable with Elixir or Erlang? (one which I can `chmod +x binary_name` and then run from the same directory with `./binary_name`)

Comment: If you're trying to build a native binary, you might also want to look at this: http://erlang.org/doc/man/HiPE_app.html.  Sort of a way to produce binary code for Erlang/Elixir as opposed to byte code which is interpreted by the BEAM.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Escripts support that to some extent but you still need Erlang installed in your machine. See this answer for more information: [Elixir or Hex portable package format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24500994/elixir-or-hex-portable-package-format)

EDIT: In 2023, [burrito](https://github.com/burrito-elixir/burrito)/[bakeware](https://github.com/bake-bake-bake/bakeware) are also valid answers, as mentioned by @Dorian.

Comment: Thanks, portability is exactly the reason I was asking. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

Make sure you checkout [Distillery](https://github.com/bitwalker/distillery). It does what you need, without having to deal with Rebar.

Add this to your *mix.exs* file's dependencies then run `mix release`.

```
defp deps do
  [{:distillery, "~> 0.9"}]
end
```

Their documentation is great:

- [Home - Distillery Documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/distillery/home.html)

Answer (score 10):

You can use tools like [rebar](https://github.com/erlang/rebar3) to generate a release that also contains the erts, which makes it possible to run said release on a machine where erlang is not installed. But the erts included corresponds to the operating system on which the release was built, i.e. windows binaries if built on windows.

Answer (score 5):

You can use **Elixir's built-in releases** as of Elixir 1.9. It is a lightweight alternative to [Distillery](https://github.com/bitwalker/distillery).

**Caveats:**
It will not create anything remotely like Go does with a single binary executable that you can run almost anywhere. Also your target will have to match the CPU architecture and OS.

To build a release run:

```sh
mix release
```

Read more here:
https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Release.html

Answer (score 3):

There are a few tools now that allow you to create a self contained executable binary that doesn't require any dependencies on the target machine. They support multiple platforms.

Bakeware: https://github.com/bake-bake-bake/bakeware

Burrito: https://github.com/burrito-elixir/burrito