# How to create a exe file from an elixir project

Tags: windows, command-line, exe, elixir

I am new to elixir and I am trying to create a command line app for Windows. I would like to deploy the app as an exe file that can be run from command prompt. I would also like the end user to not be required to install erlang to run the app if possible.

I have looked everywhere on Google and found nothing that seemed to help. I have installed Rebar3 but I don't know if that is what I need or not.

EDIT: I am currently using escript to run the app but I still have to type "escript app_name [args]" and I want to just run it as "app_name [args]".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can elixir or erlang programs be compiled to a standalone binary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31861544/can-elixir-or-erlang-programs-be-compiled-to-a-standalone-binary)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a release with exrm. Include it in your app dependencies in your mix file and then you'll be able to do something like : `MIX_ENV=prod mix do compile, release`

It will generate a tarball that  contains everything you need to run your app. Including a bat file to start it on windows. It might not be a exe as you requested in your question, but it's still easy to from windows CLI

you'll find more information in the Phoenix doc (most of it applies to elixir apps without phoenix): http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/advanced-deployment